# How to get null value instead of empty string with Glass Mapper?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc, glass-mapper

I would like to get null value instead of empty string for 'Single-Line Text' field type with Glass Mapper.

I need to recognize if any value was set or if a field was reseted to default state (and I expect there is no value - null).

Do you know if it's possible?

Comment: When you say 'reset to default state', are you checking for the Standard Value of the field? If so, you can leverage the .ContainsStandardValue property of the underlying Field.

Comment: Yes, I can do it like this but problem is I am using Glass Mapper and I get model with values. But if I will create custom handler, definitely I will use this property. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to write a custom Glass.Mapper data handlers.

Check this post:

[Custom data handlers](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2015/10/30/extending-media-item-templates-with-custom-glass-mapper-data-handlers/)

Comment: Thank you Vlad for the link. Probably I will write this handler. And if I will do it, I will post my code..